# Is there a way to configure an EKS service to use HTTPS?

Tags: service, https, kubernetes, amazon-eks

Here is the config for our current EKS service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: main-api
  name: main-api-svc
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type: nlb
spec:
  externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  ports:
    - name: http-port
      port: 80
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 80
  selector:
    app: main-api
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: LoadBalancer
```

is there a way to configure it to use HTTPS instead of HTTP?

Comment: There are a [number of AWS-specific Service annotations](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#ssl-support-on-aws) hidden in the Kubernetes documentation; do these work on EKS?

Comment: What David said, however, I wanted to ensure you saw that [NLBs are alpha](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#aws-nlb-support) and are marked as "don't do that in production"; the TLS support for NLBs is also fairly new from the AWS side of things, so you're _really_ blazing trails and "blazing trails" and "EKS" is a recipe for a car crash

Answer (score 12):

To terminate HTTPS traffic on Amazon Elastic Kubernetes Service and pass it to a backend:

1.    [Request a public ACM certificate](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/gs-acm-request-public.html) for your custom domain.

2.    Identify the [ARN of the certificate](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/gs-acm-describe.html#gs-acm-describe-console) that you want to use with the load balancer's HTTPS listener.

3.    In your text editor, create a **service.yaml** manifest file based on the following example. Then, edit the annotations to provide the ACM ARN from step 2.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: echo-service
  annotations:
    # Note that the backend talks over HTTP.
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-backend-protocol: http
    # TODO: Fill in with the ARN of your certificate.
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-cert: arn:aws:acm:{region}:{user id}:certificate/{id}
    # Only run SSL on the port named "https" below.
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-ports: "https"

spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: echo-pod
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 80
    targetPort: 8080
  - name: https
    port: 443
    targetPort: 8080
```

4.    To create a **Service** object, run the following command:

```
$ kubectl create -f service.yaml
```

5.    To return the DNS URL of the service of type **LoadBalancer**, run the following command:

```
$ kubectl get service
```

**Note:** If you have many active services running in your cluster, be sure to get the URL of the right service of type **LoadBalancer** from the command output.

6.    Open the [Amazon EC2 console](https://console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/), and then choose **Load Balancers**.

7.    Select your load balancer, and then choose **Listeners**.

8.    For **Listener ID**, confirm that your load balancer port is set to **443**.

9.    For **SSL Certificate**, confirm that the SSL certificate that you defined in the YAML file is attached to your load balancer.

10.    [Associate your custom domain name with your load balancer name](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/using-domain-names-with-elb.html#dns-associate-custom-elb).

11.    Finally, In a web browser, test your custom domain with the following HTTPS protocol:

```
https://yourdomain.com
```

Comment: this link also helped me: https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/918#issuecomment-351231441

Comment: So there is no need for a certificate (may be self signed) for the service/pod? I am confused how the load balancer will pass the request to the service on https without a ssl certificate. Please can you help here?

Comment: @Vishal Usually all the nodes of the cluster are inside a private network, so you don't need HTTPS there and you can safely terminate the SSL/TLS connections at load balancer level

Answer (score 0):

You should use an ingress (and not a service) to expose http/s outside of the cluster
I suggest using the [ALB Ingress Controller](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-alb-ingress-controller)

There is a complete walkthrough [here](https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-alb-ingress-controller/guide/walkthrough/echoserver/)

and you can see how to setup  TLS/SSL [here](https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-alb-ingress-controller/guide/ingress/annotation/#ssl)

Comment: Some of these links are now dead unfortunately.

Comment: walthrough link is now https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-load-balancer-controller/v2.4/examples/echo_server/

Answer (score 0):

although it is http, isn't it secure by default, since it is protected within your own VPC and private security subnet.